# UITableView with two types of cells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

[image]

`UITableView` contains, suppose, 50 rows. The first row contains one item and every even row index  cell contains two items?
for that we need to use two `XIB` view for each alternate row?

What would be the logic for totalrowcount and `cellAtRowatindexpath` logic?

**Is there any other option?**

Comment: you can make two sections. section 0-row 1,section 1- 49row

Comment: try to define 2 cell identefires

Comment: The question is not clear. In the question, you mentioned that your first cell is different and all the other cells are the same. However, your comments on some answers suggests that you have alternating cells; all odds and evens are the same.

Comment: You should make it more clear and give some information about your cell structures and data source, so that we can comment on the logic.

Comment: updated uitableview structure

Comment: Thanks, I assumed the same structure and was working on an answer based on it. See my answer below. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine your table looks like this:

```
+---------------------+
|        Data 1       |  --> Cell Type 1
+---------------------+
|  Data 2  |  Data 3  |  --> Cell Type 2
+---------------------+
|        Data 4       |
+---------------------+
|  Data 5  |  Data 6  |
+---------------------+
.         ...         .
```

First of all, you should design two different `UITableViewCell` nibs for those cell types. Personally, I would use Storyboard, design two dynamic cells with different identifiers and call them when needed. For example:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                              reuseIdentifier:@"Cell Type 1"];
```

Let's get to tableView's data source methods. I assume that the data is stored in an array called `self.tableData`. You can build a logic to return the number of rows as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return ceil([self.tableData count]*(2.0f/3.0f));
}
```

And then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, return these cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    NSUInteger objectIndex = floor(indexPath.row*(3.0f/2.0f));

    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        // define cell as Cell Type 1 from nib
        cell.yourLabel.text = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:objectIndex];
    } else {
        // define cell as Cell Type 2 from nib
        cell.yourLabel1.text = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:objectIndex];
        cell.yourLabel2.text = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:(objectIndex+1)];
    }

   return cell;
}
```

Note that, I am assuming your `tableData` array contains something like `NSString` objects and you have `UILabel`'s on your cells. The above code fetches the objects from your data source from the corresponding indices and populates your labels.

Comment: There was a mistake in calculating the indices for returning objects from the data source array. I believe I fixed it, now it should work.

Comment: total row count calculation is exact ,suppose i have 5 data in row, need to display in above format, calculation went wrong : count *(2.0/3.0) is getting 3.33 not four...any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the `ceil` function? For example a quick test: `NSLog(@"%f", ceil(5*(2.0f/3.0f)));`, the output is `4.000000`.

Answer (score 0):

totalrowcount stands 50

**cellForRowAtIndexpath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // make 2 cellidentifiers here and use it for different nib
    UITableViewCell  *cell; 
    if(indexpath.row==0){
    //load first nib
    }
    else
    {
    //load second nib
    }
   return cell;
}
```

Comment: what about totalrowcount logic? every even number row contains two item row. how can we calculate total row count? we need to define row as per itemcount..

Comment: row count will dynamically change..not fixed.

Comment: @RajeshPillai why can't you pass the row count from your data source?

Comment: then keep it dynamic in the numberOfrowsInSection method

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`
 and pass 1 section here as :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

and then 
In `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method you will pass total number of rows as a datasource to the tableview.
Ex: if you have to display 50 rows then pass 50 rows as :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 50;

}
```

And in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
 you will pass the cell as per the need
    Ex:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


        if(indexPath.row %2 ==0)
    {
            // First alternaate cell which you need to display at even index
            return ALTERNATE_NIB_1;
    }
    else 
    {
            // Second alternaate cell which you need to display at odd index
        return ALTERNATE_NIB_1;
    }


return nil;
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Every even number row will display two item from the list..row count 50 is not fixed..vary as per item list..we need to calculate row as per displaying item..

Comment: @user972413 I have updated my answer. Use one section and then add cells in given conditions for alternate indexes as done in code. It will work properly

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
            //cell type 1
        } else if(indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
            //cell type 2
        }
    }
```

Above code will help you assign alternate cell pattern

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 types of cells I suggest use 2 different identifiers and when you dequeue the cells you get the cell need.